# Get pairs of reserved dates in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get the list of reservations in pairs from my database.

I am able to get the list of start and end times concatenated together but start is separate from end time.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT res.room_id, GROUP_CONCAT(res.start) as start, GROUP_CONCAT(res.end) as end
    FROM
      hotel h
      INNER JOIN reservations res ON res.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
      INNER JOIN rooms r ON r.room_id = res.room_id
    GROUP BY res.room_id
```

The result I want:

```
room_id | reserved
1       | 2019-01-01 01:00:00-2019-01-01 02:00:00, 2019-01-01 05:00:00-2019-01-01 07:00:00
```

Here is my related schema:

Hotel:

```
hotel_id | hotel_name
```

Reservation:

```
res_id | hotel_id | room_id | res_start | res_end | res_status
```

Rooms:

```
room_id | hotel_id | room_name | room_number
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use multiple arguments for `group_concat()`.

```
SELECT res.room_id,
       group_concat(res.start, '-', res.end) reserved
       FROM hotel h
            INNER JOIN reservations res
                       ON res.hotel_id = h.hotel_id
            INNER JOIN rooms r
                       ON r.room_id = res.room_id
       GROUP BY res.room_id;
```

Comment: You don't actually need `concat()`.  `group_concat()` takes multiple arguments.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Yes, but can it vary the delimiters between them?

Comment: `group_concat(res.start, '-', res.end)` does the same thing as your code.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Ah, like that... Thank's for that hint! I edited the answer.